# Possible reason for freezing meteor login with facebook on heroku

Tags: javascript, facebook, heroku, meteor

After deploying Meteor test application with login-with-facebook button, login popup appears asking for app permissions, then popup freezes with white content.

Application is using external mongolab database - which is connecting with no issues.

Here's a working app
https://prettyminimal.herokuapp.com/

tried heroku logs --tail and no errors seem to occur up there, also application is not crashing, just this freezing window.

Any ideas what might be the reason?

Comment: Try `http://prettyminimal.herokuapp.com/` to see if that works. Also did you configure your fb app's redirect uri?

Comment: redirect uri was fine by default, but switching it from https to http made everything work! Thank you :)